# Different encodings in Java and Thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, encoding, escaping, thymeleaf

I want to output special characters in the frontend. But the strings are defined in the backend. My problem is, that the html- and the java file are differently encoded and I can't see the arrow.

Example:

HTML

```
<!-- this html-file is UTF-8 encoded -->
<meta th:if="${myTags.arrow}" th:name="${myTags.arrow}" th:content="${myTags.arrow} "/>
```

Java

```
// this java-file is ISO-8859-15 encoded
class myTags {

    String arrow;

    public String getArrow() {
        arrow = "➤ #NAME# ";

        return arrow;
    }
}
```

I am not allowed to change the encodings. May you advice me? Thanks.

Comment: try using the relevant Unicode escape in your source code `arrow = "\u27a4 #NAME# ";`

Comment: When you create your `SpringResourceTemplateResolver`, do you set `resolver.setCharacterEncoding` to something that can display the arrow?  The arrow works for me with `resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");`